# How to set password options in Identity Server 4

Tags: identityserver4

Im setting up IdentityServer4 with Asp.net identity.

How do I configure items such as the minimum password length and whether a digit is required?

Normally when configuring Identity in an MVC project I do this:

```
    manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
    {
        RequiredLength = 6,
        RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
        RequireDigit = false,
        RequireLowercase = false,
        RequireUppercase = false,
    };
```

But I don't know how to set this in my ID4 project.

In my startup.cs I have the following:

```
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddMvc();

    services.Configure<IISOptions>(iis =>
    {
        iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
        iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
    });

    var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
    {
        options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;

    })
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApis())
        .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
        .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would need to configure that as options.

```
  services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            //options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true; 

            //User validator
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

            //Password Validator
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```